# jQuery content loaded via .load() but href link not working

Tags: jquery, href, innerhtml

I have a problem with HTML content loaded with .load().  I have an 'accordion' menu that is working great, and on clicking an item in the menu there's a small jquery code used to load the required content into the assigned [div]

The problem I'm having is that on some of the pages that are loaded there are some href="" links. Clicking these links does not cause the 'next' page to load into the div, but instead actually forces a reload of the main page (as though you'd just pressed the RELOAD button on the browser)...

**menu.js (snipped)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".Page1").click(function () {
        $("#pageloadarea").load('Page1.php');
        $('head').append(
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css" type="text/css" />'
        );
        return false;
    });

    $(".Page2").click(function () {
        $("#pageloadarea").load('Page2.php');
        $('head').append(
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css" type="text/css" />'
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Menu Section (snipped) from index.php page**

```
<ul>
  <li class="button"><a href="" class="Page1">Page1</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="" class="Page2">Page2</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="Page3">Page3</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="Page4">Page4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the *index.php* page the menu is located inside `[div id="menu"]` and the content is injected/loaded into `[div id="pageloadarea"]`

Clicking on *Page1* in the menu successfully loads *Page1.php* into the `[div]`, as does clicking *Page2*, *Page3* and *Page4* (from the menu)...

Once *Page1.php* has been loaded into the `[div]` there is a standard link

```
<a href="" class="Page2">Page 2</a>
```

This is the link that does not work. I have numerous sub-pages that have `[a href]` links within them and none of them work once the main content has been through the `.load()` process...

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click",".Page1", function () {
        $("#pageloadarea").load('Page1.php');
        $('head').append(
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css" type="text/css" />'
        );
        return false;
    });

    $(document).on("click",".Page2", function () {
        $("#pageloadarea").load('Page2.php');
        $('head').append(
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css" type="text/css" />'
        );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Use this as it will bind the event to new loaded DOM elements also.

Comment: @KailashYadav I also faced the same problem. This solution saved my day. Thnxx Kailash !

Answer (score 1):

You need to attach all the event handlers to he links once your now page loads or use delegation.

Delegation Example

HTML link:

```
<!-- add a class to filter ajax links on "ajaxify", also use the HREF attribute
     For the page to be loaded - not sure whay you arent doing that now... -->
<a href="Page2.php" class="Page2 ajaxify">Page2</a>
```

JS

```
// use delegation to attatch the event handlers

$(function(){
   $(document).on('click', 'a.ajaxify', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent normal link navigation
        var $this = $(this),
            url = $this.attr('href');

        $("#pageloadarea").load(url);
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/style.css" type="text/css" />');

        return false; 
   });
});
```

By using delegation the handler is attached to the `document` element and when a click event is bubbled up it is filtered... if the trigger was an `a.ajaxify` then the handler will be invoked. This allows you to handle instances of `a.ajaxify` that were not in the DOM when you first attached the handler.

Comment: I wasn't populating the HREF attribute with "Page2.php" at the time, because clicking the link on Page1 (loaded into the [div]) forced PAge2 to load fully for some reason, rather than into the [div id="pageloadarea"] section (as though there was an implied target="_self"). By leaving the HREF as "" it did load properly...

Comment: Thats because you didnt call `preventDefault()` on the click event.